# Binding duration from storyboard dynamically in a UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm barely new at WPF, and I'm trying to set duration dynamically.

What I've tried:

- usercontrol.xaml

```
 <UserControl.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Key="ProgressBarAnimation" 
                    TargetName="arc" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">

            <PointAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                                     Duration="{Binding D1, ElementName=thisControl}">

                <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>

                    <PathGeometry Figures="M 0 -100 A 100 100 0 0 1 0 100
                                                    A 100 100 0 0 1 0 -100" />

                </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>

            </PointAnimationUsingPath>

            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsLargeArc"
                                            Duration="0:0:40">

                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                         Value="False" />

                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:20"
                                         Value="True" />

            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        </Storyboard>
```

- usercontrol.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class usercontrol : UserControl
    {


        public string D1
        {
            get {
                return (string)GetValue(D1Property); }
            set {
                SetValue(D1Property, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for D1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty D1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("D1", typeof(string), typeof(usercontrol), new PropertyMetadata("0:0:40"));



        public usercontrol()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

As you can see in my usercontrol.xaml at PointAnimationUsingPath, I've tried to bind its duration to my D1 property, but seems like it doesn't work. So I hope someone could help me with it.

**EDIT**
I've tried switching from string to Duration or TimeSpan and didn't work as well.

Comment: `string D1` should certainly be `TimeSpan D1` or `Duration D1`. Make sure you take notice of data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug your application.

Comment: @Clemens I've tried it and doesn't work as well...